# Error while passing some 80 requests through API for load testing in JMeter.

Tags: testing, load, jmeter

I am trying to perform the load test through J Meter by putting load of around 80 requests at a time. Few response go through fine but few errors with the below response error.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.sample(HTTPJavaImpl.java:487)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1088)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1077)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:428)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Could this be issue from J Meter side or server side? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If it works fine with few requests & it is failing with 80 requests at a time, then it could be app server issue. Definitely you should be seeing some exceptions in the log in case the server is not responding. If you are not checking, you should do that. You also need to have monitoring tools to monitor server performance.